# How do I turn off _all_ optimizations in Clang++?

Tags: debugging, c++11, optimization, lldb, clang++

I'm trying to debug some C++11 code, and LLDB is being unhelpful. The code looks roughly like this:

```
void f(my_type dt) {
   try {
      g(h(dt));
   }
   catch ( /* reasonable exception type here */ ) {
   }
}
```

When I place a breakpoint on the `g(h(dt))` line, LLDB insists that the value of `dt` is unavailable. It most certainly cannot have been elided away, as it is used in the implementation of `h` as input to some database queries.

I use CMake, and it compiles using the following flags:

```
CXX_FLAGS = -g -O0 -fPIC -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall
```

I confirmed (using `make VERBOSE=true`) that these flags are, indeed, being used to build the project. As far as I can determine, full debugging information should be included and all optimizations turned off. This clearly is not the case. **What other flags can I add to force Clang to keep all parameters and variables available throughout the calling stack?**

Unfortunately, small test cases using small files and functions do not reproduce this problem: most of the time, the variable is preserved as I expect.

I'm working on a Mac running Yosemite.

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: `-fno-inline` maybe?

Comment: No, `-fno-inline` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's most likely a bug in the compiler.  At -O0 it should always keep variables live during their defining block.  It actually probably is, but somebody lost track of where it was somewhere in the compiler pipeline.

If you can cons up some example that shows this issue which you don't mind sharing with the llvm folks, then please file a bug either with the llvm bugzilla (http://llvm.org/bugs/) or with the Apple llvm team at http://bugreport.apple.com.